# I want to redirect the duplicates into another file without using sort command

Tags: file, sorting, unix, duplicates

I want to redirect the duplicates into another file without using sort command.

I have tried using the following command but it didn't work.

```
uniq -d sample.txt
```

It works only when I give it as "`sort sample.txt | uniq -d`", but I want to take out the duplicates of a file without sorting the file.
Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: `awk` programming might help. I'd do it with PHP, Perl, Python, C# or something...or if the data is organized, I'd store it in a DB capable of doing row_number over(...). If dataset is small, use SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it done with this simple `awk` command:

```
awk 'a[$0]{print;next}{a[$0]=1}' sample.txt
```

Here, `$0` => the current complete line being processed. if `a[$0]` is already set, print the line (this is a duplicate line) and proceed to `next` line. Else `a[$0]` is set, so next time the same line (if present) will be taken as duplicate.

**Example:**

```
AMD$ cat sample.txt
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 1
Line 4
Line 5
Line 2
Line 6
Line 7
Line 7
Line 8
Line 3
Line 9
Line 10
AMD$ awk 'a[$0]{print;next}{a[$0]=1}' sample.txt
Line 1
Line 2
Line 7
Line 3
```